# Where can i find the nice Processing Gif file

Tags: image, image-processing

Where can i find the nice Processing Gif file

I found few on google images. but when i try downloading them, its getting downloaded as an image.

Please help me.

Comment: I am sorry, but your question is unclear. Do you need gif file? Or code that knows to process gif files?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, especially not the second part - what else  if not an image would you expect?

Comment: I would need a Processing GIF file to put it in my website.

Comment: Ahh, so you get only static images from Google Images? That is normal. You need to go to the animated source file on the website the image is on, and download it from there. However ajaxload.info suggested by Matt is the much better (and always legal) choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for http://ajaxload.info. They're all images, though - **that's what a GIF is.**

Answer (score 0):

Here another one ,explains what types you need.

http://qureyoon.blogspot.com/2006/11/make-your-own-loading-gif.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're opening with the default windows image viewer. It doesn't show gif animations. try opening them in your browser if that's the case.